# Ensuring data is properly stored in c++ array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, memory-management

I have a large code I'm trying to integrate into an existing program. For this, I need to work with c++ 2d and 1d arrays. I'm most familiar with python; if I tried

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros(10)
x[20] = 3
print(x[15])
```

Both lines 3 and 4 would cause an error to occur. In c++, this doesn't cause an error, instead a segfault will likely occur somewhere in the code (or the computed answer is meaningless). My question is, how can I ensure memory assignment/access in a c++ array is correct? Are the compiler options or debugging tools that would help with this? I am using g++ to compile the code.

Comment: c++ containers have an `at` method that can error on out of bounds access

Comment: Don't use dumb C++ arrays and use a smarter array container, i.e. `std::array` or `std::vector`.  There is no way, other than putting in checks in your code, to stop a C++ array access from an out-of-bounds access.  C++ was designed this way so that if you don't want checking, the array is as fast as possible.  Not so with other languages, where the check will slow down a program (even just slightly).

Comment: I fear for code which "tries" to access some data somewhere "in hope" to find some values. Which kind of code access data in that way? Maybe there is some user input to request some index. OK. But if any algorithm is iterating or accessing data, the access to not available data should never happen.

Comment: if you use algorithms and range-based for loops, it is actually not that common that you need to access an element by its index (without being certain that the index is valid).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The questioner mentions wanting 2d arrays, for which C++ support is woefully inadequate until we get `md_span` in 23. You could of course `x.at(i).at(j)` but that implies a `vector<vector<int>>` which I would never advocate.

Answer (score 0):

With raw arrays, there is no way except if you keep track of the actual size yourself.

In C++, you only pay for what you use. In other words, the bounds checking is up to the developer to implement so that it won't penalize someone who does not actually need it.

A good practice is to not use raw arrays but use standard containers instead (`std::array`, `std::vector`, ...). They own their data and keep track of the size for you.

With standard containers, there is an `at()` member function that throws an [`std::out_of_range` exception](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) if you try to access an out of bounds index.
On the other hand, if you don't want to handle the exception, you still can do the bounds checking manually using the `size()` member function.

---

One valid implementation of your example bay be:

```
std::vector<int> x(10, 0); // Vector of 10 elements initialized with value 0
```

- Bounds checking with exception handling:

```
try
{
    x.at(12) = 3; // at()
}
catch(std::exception & e)
{
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

- Manual bounds checking:

```
if(12 < x.size())
    x[12] = 3; // operator[]
```

<sub>***Note:** `std::vector` requires to `#include <vector>` and `std::array` requires to `#include <array>`.*</sub>

Answer (score -1):

The compiler will warn you if you use a literal index like shown in your question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        int thing[2] = {0};
        printf("%d", thing[3]);
        return 0;
}
```

```
test.cpp:5:15: warning: array index 3 is past the end of the array (which contains 2 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
        printf("%d", thing[3]);
                     ^     ~
test.cpp:4:2: note: array 'thing' declared here
        int thing[2] = {0};
        ^
1 warning generated.
```

It will not, however, generate an error if you use a variable to index into the array, and the value of that variable is out-of-range. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int thing[2] = {0};
    int index = 3;
    printf("%d", thing[index]);
    return 0;
}
```

The behaviour here is undefined, and the compiler won't let you know. The best you can do in these cases is put a check in place before the array access.

Comment: This answer describes the behavior of a particular (and unspecified) compiler. None of the behavior that it describes is required by the language definition, so don't rely on any of this happening.

Comment: @PeteBecker seems pedantic given the skill level of the question and the ubiquity of this compiler feature

Comment: If you've reviewed a bunch of compilers and seen that they all do what you claim you should say so rather than making unsupported claims of "ubiquity". At the very least, mention what compiler you're talking about.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here exactly? The point you're labouring to make doesn't enhance the answer; if you're looking for a curated list of esoteric compilers that don't implement bounds-checks, perhaps post it as your own question?

Comment: @InigoSelwood The point is that the question was about C++ not about how compilers may or may not implement it. What is not explicitly mentioned in the standard specification cannot being taken for granted because you have no guarantee it will always apply. If the OP expressed the need to consider a specific compiler (and a specific version), that would be another story of course :)